# pseudo-resources (using configuraton qualifiers) at runtime

Tags: android, eclipse

I am creating an app which utilizes images from local device folders (brought back from server) at runtime rather than from the app's own resources folders.

I would like to take advantage of Android's runtime ability to use the appropriate resource files for different display types/orientation, similar to its present runtime usage of different resource folders (ldpi, hdpi, sw600sp etc) but in my case, not actually with complete resource folder content present during the app build.

Which would be the preferred methodology to achieve this?

i) pulling back the server images files and creating a sub-directory structure recognized by Android in a similar fashion as it presently recognizes its res directory structure -- i.e. a runtime pseudo-resource folder if you like.

ii) overriding events to catch orientation changes on existing activities and manually determining display type at start-up, in order to point all the app's activities to appropriate (locally stored at runtime) image files.

I am not entirely sure how to achieve either of the above, hence any indication of preference and general approach would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Android's resource identification mechanism for this too. You can create the different images on your server and you can store the links to this in your strings.xml
So you will have different strings.xml in different res/values-xx folders (where xx stands for the configuration qualifiers). Take a look at [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) to know more about the configuration qualifiers.

so in values-ldpi, your strings.xml can have a value as:

```
<string name="icon">http://my-server/images/icon-ldpi.jpg</string>
```

whereas the strings.xml in values-hdpi will have the value as:

```
<string name="icon">http://my-server/images/icon-hdpi.jpg</string>
```

and so on.

**Edit**:
In case the url contains runtime parameters, you can specify the same in the strings.xml as:

```
<string name="icon">http://my-server/%1$s/images/icon-ldpi.jpg</string>
```

And you use the same in the Java code as follows:

```
String iconURL = getResources().getString(R.string.icon, siteId);
```

If the `siteID` is 001, depending on the device type, the imageURL would be "`http://my-server/001/images/icon-ldpi.jpg`" or "`http://my-server/001/images/icon-mdpi.jpg`" or "`http://my-server/001/images/icon-hdpi.jpg`" or ... And the fact is that you don't have to do anything in your code to determine the display attributes for this to work.

Comment: I am unable to do it this way, as the server directories are different for different users e.g. http://my-server/<siteid>/images etc. Where siteid is determined at runtime.  Unfortunately this still does not answer my question re: the best way to point at resources only made available at runtime, and how to point the app to those resources based on device-side runtime-determined configuration qualifiers.

Comment: You can use the idea at least - instead of the complete url, use just the name of the image file. Also, take note that the [String Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) support parameters. So it is perfectly possible to create http://my-server/%s/images where %s is replaced by siteid during runtime.  I guess you have not understood the answer completely. I will try to add more explanation.

Comment: I see.  Thanks Rajesh for the explanation -- I was not aware that I could pass formatting parameters into the string. Quick question: As my app already uses language specific values folders e.g. values-pt, values-de, values-pt-land etc. which contain their own independent strings.xml files, am I correct in assuming that, because I intend to use parameters, I am unable to use resource aliases? Or just specify duplicated format arguments in all strings.xml files?

Comment: The "Providing Resources" link above has a section on How Android Finds the Best-matching Resource. That should help you in answering your question. Yes, you can use the resource aliases together with the language specific value folders. Please give it a try.

Comment: I have just thought of a problem with this -- this method (using a returned 'resource' path based on the device's display resolution, locale and orientation) presumes I will have the given file available, which will not always be the case. i.e. if locale is Portuguese and device in landscape mode then it will return path to icon-pt-land.jpg -- if it doesn't exist, I need to also then check for icon-pt.jpg, and if it also does not exist, then use default icon.jpg.  Calls to getResources.getString will always return the same 'built' (from params) path.

Comment: You still do not seem to have understood the answer. What I was saying is that provide image urls for different configs - you'll get the url that you have specified. Android will not create icon-pt-land.jpg for you, you'll have to specify that in the values-pt-land/strings.xml. If you know that you have to use icon.jpg for pt-land config, specify it in place of icon-pt-land.jpg. Of course if this information can be known only dynamically, you may not be able to use this method. Why don't you do a sample project with different string values and test it on emulators of different resolutions?

Comment: I think I do understand what you have said Rajesh, however I need the resource applied to be dictated by what image file is available on the server. For example, if I call String iconURL = getResources.getString(R.string.icon, siteId), and the applied strings.xml returns target string "<path>/images/icon-ldpi.jpg", then this file HAS to exist on the server. If it does not, I wanted the behaviour whereby I can use "<path>/images/icon.jpg" (if it exists) instead. Note: This is simplified example, as it does not allow for icon-pt.jpg, icon-pt-land.jpg etc.

Answer (score 0):

This has turned out to be easier than I thought.  I can just return 'identifier' strings stored in assorted values-xxx folders in order to build an appropriate set of possible file names.

e.g.
In values\string.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Resource Tester</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="myindicator_lang">en</string>
    <string name="myindicator_dpi">normal</string>
    <string name="myindicator_orient">port</string>
</resources>
```

In values-de\string.xml:

```
<resources>   <string name="myindicator_lang">de</string>   </resources>
```

In values-land\string.xml:

```
<resources>   <string name="myindicator_orient">land</string>   </resources>
```

In values-hdpi\string.xml:

```
<resources>   <string name="myindicator_dpi">hdpi</string>   </resources>
```

etc.

With this string info returned at runtime, I can just dynamically build the required file name based on device configuration, allowing me to store alternative server/local storage resources with an appropriate name and have my app utilise the most appropriate image file if it exists.

i.e. in server/local storage have:

```
mybanner-en.jpg
mybanner-de.jpg
mybanner-de-land.jpg
```

etc.

I can now search for an existing stored file which best matches the device config at the time.

Many thanks Rajesh, for pointing me in the right direction.